# django datefield is not store in MYSQL database correctly

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am using django and MYSQL. Below is my models.py:

```
enter code here

    from django.db import models 
    from django.utils import timezone 
    import datetime
    from django.utils.translation import gettext as _ 
    from bootstrap4_datetime.widgets import DateTimePicker 
    from django import forms

class Post(models.Model):
    WEEKDAYS=(
        ('Mon','Monday'),
        ('Tue','Tuesday'),
        ('Wed','Wednesday'),
        ('Thu','Thursday'),
        ('Fri','Friday'),
        )
    TIMES=(
        ('morning','上午'),
        ('afternoon','下午'),
        ('night','晚上'),
        )
    CUSTOMERS=(
        ('中兴','ZTE'),
        ('比特大陆','BITMAIN'),
        ('松果','PINECONE'),
        ('飞思卡尔','FREESCALE'),
        ('大唐','DATANG'),
        )
    weekday = models.CharField(max_length=50,default='Mon',choices=WEEKDAYS)
    time = models.CharField(max_length=50,default='morning',choices=TIMES)
    customer = models.CharField(max_length=50,default='ZTE',choices=CUSTOMERS)
    pub_date = models.DateField(_("Date"), default=datetime.datetime.now().date)


class Meta:
    ordering = ('-pub_date',)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.pub_date
```

Here is database record：

```
13  2018-01-02 00:00:00.000000  中兴  morning Mon
14  2018-01-08 00:00:00.000000  中兴  morning Mon
```

The database table shows the full time ,but I think datefield will only return format：YY-MM-DD。How to do to store date in YY-MM-DD format.

Thanks!